# "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address" for communication between Jetson TX2 Board and PC host

Tags: networking, ip, drone.io, nvidia-jetson, eoserror

I think the IP address and port number are correct checked by using ifconfig at server side, and the port is not bind by others at server side. So, I guess the problem is at client side. I have attached the running results at client side and netstat result on server side (PC). They are all under the same wifi. Server IP is 10.42.0.197 and port # is 14450, the client ip is 10.42.0.1. The client side (TX2 board) still cannot bind the ip and port.
[image].
[image]

Comment: Please add these logs as _text_ not as _images_ to make things easier for people wanting to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the interface associated with the IP you wanted to bind on client side. If you did not find any related IP then there is no associated connection with this IP. Resolve the connection issue and retry. Use `netstat` or `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` to check interfaces. This command vary per OS, check for the one that supports.